# HorizontalPager's user gesture overrides ModalNavigationDrawer's gesture

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Consider this piece of code:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun TestPreview() {
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(initialValue = DrawerValue.Closed)
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(initialPage = 0) { 2 }

    AppTheme {
        Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            ModalNavigationDrawer(drawerState = drawerState, gesturesEnabled = true, drawerContent = {
                ModalDrawerSheet(Modifier.width(300.dp)) {
                    Text("Test")
                }
            }, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), content = {
                Scaffold { padding ->
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .padding(padding),
                    ) {
                        TabRow(
                            selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage, containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer
                        ) {
                            for (index in 0..<2) {
                                Tab(text = { Text("$index") }, selected = pagerState.currentPage == index, onClick = {
                                    scope.launch {
                                        pagerState.animateScrollToPage(index)
                                    }
                                })
                            }
                        }

                        HorizontalPager(
                            state = pagerState,
                            key = { it },
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                            userScrollEnabled = true,
                        ) {
                            when (it) {
                                0 -> Text("Tab 0")
                                1 -> Text("Tab 1")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

It's a minimal version of the Android app I'm building. As you can see, I'm using an HorizontalPager to have multiple tabs, and I want the user to be able to scroll through the pages. I also have a ModalNavigationDrawer, which I would like to also be opened with a user gesture. The problem is that I can't have both work at the same time. I've noticed that changing the size of the two elements does make them work together (but it messes up all the layout of the content), which leads me to think that HorizontalPager is completely covering the ModalNavigationDrawer's area. I've tried having HorizontalPager smaller on the left to have a space which can make ModalNavigationDrawer's gesture work, but it's a nightmare to adjust the content to also occupy that left space.

Is there a simpler way to have them both work at the same time?